# VBA - Subtotal gives the minimum value a a column, how can I get the row of that value?

Tags: excel, vba

Could you please help me finding out how can I find the row of the minimum value that the subtotal gave me?

Like this:

```
    A           B          C        D       E       F       G
1  Galp         He        0,15     125                   0,15443
3  Iberdrola    Au        0,18     123                   0,16987
7  Gazprom      Sc        0,25     430                   0,14679
```

I run the code to find the minimum value on the filtered Column G:

```
Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(5, Columns("G"))
```

It gets me the number `0,14679`. But I need to know what row it is so I can get the name on the column A (`Gazprom`).

Vlookup doesn't work on this case because I have more than 1 value with the same caracteristics. But they are not visible like it's showed on the example above. Line two that is not visible has the same value of line 3 (0,16987).

However, following the suggestion of @Mrig if I use Subtotal 105 can I get the visible column?

I've been trying the code and it returns me error 13...

How can I find the name on row A of the minimum value of filtered column G?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim min As Double
    Dim rowNum As Long

    With Sheet3
        min = Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(5, Columns("A"))
        rowNum = .Columns(1).Find(What:=min, After:=.Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False).Row
        MsgBox ("Minimum value is " & min & " at row number " & rowNum & ". Corresponding column B value is " & Cells(rowNum, 2).Value)
    End With
End Sub
```

Subtotal with 5 as function number will give minimum value from the selected range including hidden rows. Subtotal with 105 as function number gives minimum value only from visible range.

Comment: What error does it give you? Also, make sure you mention the correct sheet in the With statement. In my code its Sheet3.

Comment: Run time error 91.... Can't make it work like that. Something is missing on the code...

Comment: Replace LookIn:=xlValues with LookIn:=xlFormulas

Answer (score 0):

You will need to search only visible items for the required value.  Something like this

```
Sub FindMin()
    Dim rng As Range, arr As Range, cl As Range
    Dim SearchTerm As Variant, LookUpTerm  As Variant
    Dim Found As Boolean

    SearchTerm = Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(5, Columns("A"))

    With ActiveSheet
        Set rng = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
    End With

    For Each arr In rng.Areas
        For Each cl In arr.Cells
            If cl.Value = SearchTerm Then
                LookUpTerm = cl.Offset(, 1) ' adjust offset to refer to required column
                Found = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next cl
        If Found Then Exit For
    Next arr
```

Finds the *First Visible* instance

---

Original answer, without the Filtered requirement

To answer your direct Q "how to get the row..." use

```
rw = Application.Match(Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(5, Columns("A")), Columns("A"), 0)
```

To get the value from column `B` directly use

```
ColBVal = Application.VLookup(Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(5, Columns("A")), Columns("A:B"), 2, 0)
```

Note that if the minimum value appears more than once these will return the first occurrence.

Comment: Why do you use the number 2 in the ColBVal?

Comment: The `VLOOKUP` function parameters are _VLOOKUP(lookup_value,table_array,col_index_num,range_lookup)_  In this case _col_index_ is 2, ie column `B`

Comment: @joao you have raised a number of new points in comments.  Please edit this info into your _question_.

Comment: Why the 1's on `Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1)` ?